# How do I fit my custom view to parent size if MeasureSpec is UNSPECIFIED in android?

Tags: android, android-view

I'm writing my custom view and I would like to make it the same width as parent is. And parent is `RecyclerView` which scrolls horizontally. So I receive `widthMeasureSpec` in my `onMeasure` method with `size = 0` and `mode = UNSPECIFIED`.

So how do I know parent's width ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, width is infinite because it scrolls horizontally. If you want it to have the same width w/ RecyclerView, use `recyclerView.getWidth()`. You can use the RecyclerView instance passed to onCreateView.